# Is it safe to dpkg --set-selections on a newer version of a distro?

Tags: debian, dpkg, dist-upgrade, devuan

I saved my `dpkg --get-selections` on my Devuan ASCII (~= Debian Stretch). I've now reinstalled my system cleanly and dist-upgraded to Devuan Beowulf (~= Debian Buster).

Is it safe for me to now `dpkg --set-selections`? If not, can I filter out the unsafe selections and use the rest?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is. All that can go wrong is that you end up attempting to select packages which have been removed; in that situation,

> unknown packages will be ignored with a warning.

(See [the `dpkg` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg).)

You could also end up selecting deprecated packages; however you’ll end up with the appropriate transitional packages. (This could be more troublesome if you were skipping a release.)

Another possibility is that you select conflicting packages (between your selection and the upgraded packages), but the follow-up `apt` should be able to sort that out, or at least give you enough information for you to sort it out.

Debian, and presumably Devuan, cope fine with upgrades without re-installing, which would avoid your conundrum entirely. My main Debian system is running a Debian install which has been upgraded over the years going back to Debian 2.0!